# How to set up PHP-FPM on Apache?

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, php, php-fpm

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.2

My site is with Drupal 8

How to set up PHP-FPM on Apache?

I find only tutorial for NGINX or are outdated.

Comment: 1st link I found does not seem to be outdated: https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-run-apache2-with-php7-2-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/ as it is made early this year.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you. Before my site was configured like this https://pastebin.com/SvH3SBvJ and https://pastebin.com/rEqgFDxq is this method still news? In the tutorial there is nothing to configure. Why ?

Comment: @Rinzwind I also found this https://tutoandco.colas-delmas.fr/developpement/installer-php7-2-php7-2-fpm-debian/ It's still different :-( why is there nothing to configure ?

Comment: You haven't paid attention. Of course there is something to configure: `a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif && a2enconf php7.2-fpm`.

Comment: @AlexP I already activated the mods For the tutorial does not talk about server configuration and pool? Are my files corect ?

Answer (score 2):

This will install PHP 7.2 as a service.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install php-fpm
```

This tells the PHP to start as a service, listen to localhost at port: 9000.

All you now need is to tell Apache to use this service instead of trying to load PHP as a library, old style.

Make sure Apache is not trying that load PHP as a library. Look inside your main apache config - `httpd.conf` and search for something starting with `LoadModule php`. If it is there, put it within a comment tag, save and reload your apache.

Now tell Apache to use PHP you have running on port 9000. I normally do it in my vhost config. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/somewhere/on/you/filesystem"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000//somewhere/on/you/filesystem/$1
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You also need to make sure these Apache modules runs. On my system I was req. to enable these:

`LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so`